# PHP login script - Possible session errors

Tags: php, session, login-script

I am working on a login system for a client and I have run into an issue that I am unsure how to fix.  I have it set so that when the user tries to access the index.php of a certain directory they are require to login.  The code that I have doing this is:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if(!$_SESSION['myusername']){
      header("location:Login_admin.php");
   }
?>
```

On the Login_admin.php page, there is a form with the action="checklogin.php".  here is where it connects to the database and starts a session where it stores the username:

```
if($count==1){
   session_start();
   // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
   $_SESSION['myusername'];
   $_SESSION['mypassword']; 
   header("location:index.php");
}
```

Originally the above code did not have the session_start() so I added that in in attempt to solve my problem.

The actual problem is the session is not registering.  If I go to one of the other pages in the director (all of them have that first segment of code at teh top) and log in it sends me to index.php like I want, but when I try to go back to that page it makes me log in again.  At one point I had that first segment of code on my index page and even with the correct log in it would loop back to the login page.

I was shown this script by a friend and have not really changed much.  Originally the script had:

```
session_register("myusername");
```

But after some debugging, I changed it to:

```
$_SESSION['myusername'];
```

A final note, I am not an expert the issue is probably considered a silly mistake but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both of the answers below helped me solve the issue.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the

```
$_SESSION['myusername'];
```

line does **absolutely** nothing
to assign a value to session variable you have to **assign** a **value** to session variable
the usual way values being assigned to variables in PHP

Comment: The correct way would be to do: $_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername; ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a value to each session variable

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = 'thename';
$_SESSION['password'] = '*******';
```